# angulajs ng-pattern validator for input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-pattern

I am working with angularjs form validations, where i have few fields need to validate them, i will only allow the user to enter input starting with certain mix of characters and numbers(will be 7 after characters)like BID0001234, Q0001234 and PO0001234. In this case(BID0001234) i have tried these patterns '^BID/[0-9\d]*$/','^BID/^[0-9\d]*$/' and '^BID/^[0-9\d]+$/'. for some reason unable to validate it, could you someone please share the experience or direct me towards a regex pattern link that matches my issue.

update: I want to count the numbers after the BID as well, seven numbers are accepted

[`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/unGcdHZrQYXhKkSn80Ku?p=preview)

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the slashes. Try

```
ng-pattern="'^BID[0-9]+$'"
```

For exactly seven digits after "BID":

```
ng-pattern="'^BID[0-9]{7}$'"
```

Comment: user1777136, that works like charm, one thing i forgot to mention in the question, updated just now. the input should accept only seven number after characters, i tried like ^BID[0-9\d]{0,7}+$, doesn't work

Comment: Edited answer with example for 7 digits